# Adding multiple key,value pair using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python

for a list of dictionaries

```
sample_dict = [
{'a': 'woot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'duh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '1'},
{'a': 'coot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'ruh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '2'},
{'a': 'doot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'suh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '3'},
{'a': 'soot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'fuh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '4'},
{'a': 'toot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'cuh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '1'}
]
```

How do I make a separate dictionary that contains all the key,value pair that match to a certain key. With list comprehension I created a list of all the key,value pairs like this:

```
container = [[key,val] for s in sample_dict for key,val in s.iteritems() if key == 'a']
```

Now the container gave me

```
[['a', 'woot'], ['a', 'coot'], ['a', 'doot'], ['a', 'soot'], ['a', 'toot']]
```

Which is all fine... but if I want to do the same with dictionaries, I get only a singe key,value pair. Why does this happen ?

```
container = {key : val for s in sample_dict for key,val in s.iteritems() if key == 'a'}
```

The container gives only a single element

```
{'a': 'toot'}
```

I want the something like

```
{'a': ['woot','coot','doot','soot','toot']}
```

How do I do this with minimal change to the code above ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are generating multiple key-value pairs with the same key, and a dictionary will only ever store *unique* keys.

If you wanted just *one* key, you'd use a dictionary with a list comprehension:

```
container = {'a': [s['a'] for s in sample_dict if 'a' in s]}
```

Note that there is *no need* to iterate over the nested dictionaries in `sample_dict` if all you wanted was a specific key; in the above I simply test if the key exists (`'a' in s`) and extract the value for that key with `s['a']`. This is *much faster* than looping over all the keys.

Comment: I get the same result if I remove the part `if 'a' in s` from the code above... What is its significance here?

Comment: Ok that was stupid of me to ask. I get it now. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Another option:

```
filter = lambda arr, x: { x: [ e.get(x) for e in arr] }
```

So, from here, you can construct the dict based on the original array and the key

```
 filter(sample_dict, 'a')
# {'a': ['woot', 'coot', 'doot', 'soot', 'toot']}
```

Comment: This produces `None` values for a missing key, while the OP code at least simply *omits* that entry.